# Cannot display the right information in an input box from an item in a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display a specific part of an item(for example the name) in a database inside an input box but all I get is a the letter S inside the input box regardless of what is the part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "WebAssignment";
    $password ="qwer12";
    $dbname = "webassigment";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username,$password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    $selectedItem = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE Food_Name = christine pocock";
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
      Food name<br> <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($selectedItem["Food_Category"]); ?>"/>
      </form>


       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think that if you'll view the source of this page you'll find out that it's infact a php error notification

Comment: LOL! you are displaying the first letter of your SQL query 'S'. Because you haven't read about how to perform an SQL query with PHP. Have a look at this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Besides what @kangoo13 posted in the answer below, `christine pocock` lacks some single quotes, i.e. `SELECT * FROM menu WHERE Food_Name = 'christine pocock'`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to see this [tutorial](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) since what I can see from your code, you just have a SQL statement you didn't even executed it nor fetched it.

the good code would be :

```
if(!$result = $conn->query($selectedItem)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

and then to retrieve the value you just do `$row['ValueName'];`

Comment: Unless you provide explanation related specific to this question, then you should place this as a comment and not as an answer

Comment: Edited, sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was edited before or after Alon's comment, but I think it's OK now, though more explanation wouldn't hurt.